# Create multiple copies of a workbook automatically with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create multiple copies of my Excel workbook using the following VBA program:

```
Public Sub DuplicateBookMultipleTimes()

    Dim n As Integer
    On Error Resume Next

    n = InputBox("How many copies of the active workbook do you want to make?")

    If n >= 1 Then

        For numtimes = 1 To n
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\fmhijan\Desktop\Awet data transfer\" & Workbooks(Workbooks.Count) & ".xlsm"
        Next

   End If

End Sub
```

My expected outcome is to see workbooks1, workbook2, workbook3 ... depending on how many copies I want.

I get the display box and enter the number. The program runs fine but I dont see the files in the folder. Please advise. Appreciate your help.

Comment: First, remove `On Error Resume Next`. That's just hiding the error(s).

Comment: `Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)` returns a `Workbook` object. You're trying to concatenate an object into a file path, when you need a property of the object, namely its `Name`.

Comment: Also the filename never changes in the `SaveCopyAs` - so you'll just overwrite each copy.

Comment: Simply replace `Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)` with `numtimes` and declare the variable at the start of the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub DuplicateBookMultipleTimes()
   cFolder = "C:\Users\fmhijan\Desktop\Awet data transfer\"
   nCopies = InputBox("How many copies of the active workbook do you want to make?")
   If nCopies >= 1 Then
      For nLoop = 1 To nCopies
         ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs cFolder & "workbook" & nLoop & ".xlsm"
      Next
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. This code worked perfectly.  Referring to nLoop for each new workbook created is what I needed.